# Multiple independent iterators for a single dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Assume I have a training dataset "data_train", I would like to make two independent iterators that both iterate over data_train. The first iterator I will use to train my network "iter_train", where the output of iter_train.get_next() will be a batch that I train on. The second iterator will be used to evaluate the entire training dataset while I train, "iter_eval", to monitor the training progress.

Currently, if I only have a single iterator "iter_single", and I want to evaluate the training loss halfway through an epoch I will have to reset the iterator, evaluate the entire dataset with iter_single, and then begin training at the start of the dataset with iter_single. I will consequently not finish my previous epoch and ignore half the dataset unless I waste time iterating through the data without acting on it.

I already tried making two iterators for one dataset, however, by resetting one iterator it reset the other, which makes having two iterators pointless.

Comment: Please provide a minimal code example to clarify your exact problem

Answer (score 0):

**Just** in case your dataset size is not huge (by huge I mean that both training and validation data can be held into the memory during the training and evaluation), you can use the following code to:

**First**, read and parse your data and pass them through a Tensorflow dataset object:

```
def get_image_dataset(dir_path, batch_size, split=0.7):

    # Parse data and return them in array format (Numpy)
    train_data, val_data = parse_data(dir_path, split)

    # Create the dataset for our train data
    train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_data)
    train_data = train_data.batch(batch_size)

    # Create the dataset for our test data
    val_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(val_data)
    val_data = val_data.batch(batch_size)

    return train_data, val_data
```

**Second**, define an iterator and initializer for your train and validation data:

```
def get_data():
    with tf.name_scope('data'):

        train_data, test_data =  get_image_dataset(self.batch_size)
        iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(output_types=train_data.output_types, output_shapes=train_data.output_shapes)

        # Define one iterator for your data
        img, self.label = iterator.get_next()

        # Example of application on MNIST dataset
        img = tf.reshape(img, [-1, CNN_INPUT_HEIGHT, CNN_INPUT_WIDTH, CNN_INPUT_CHANNELS])

        # Define two initializers for either train or test (validation) data
        self.train_init = iterator.make_initializer(train_data)
        self.test_init = iterator.make_initializer(test_data)
```

**Third** and **Fourth**, while **training/testing** your network, initialize your Tensorflow graph with **train/test** dataset like so:

**Train**:

```
def train_network_one_epoch(...):

    # Initialize training
    sess.run(self.train_init)

    # Run training graph nodes

    return something
```

**Test**:

```
def evaluate_network(...):

    # Initialize testing
    sess.run(self.test_init)

    # Run evaluation graph nodes

    return something
```

You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/chiphuyen/stanford-tensorflow-tutorials/blob/master/examples/07_convnet_mnist.py) example which clearly demonstrates this procedure.

Comment: Thanks hexpheus, however in my case I want the train and validation dataset to be the same. This is because I want to check my loss and accuracy on the training set while I'm training. Therefore val_data = train_data. If you make this simple replacement then running sess.run(self.test_init) is the same as running sess.run(self.train_init), at least from one test I did on my own.